# pandas dataframe: set column row val equal to value of another column if several conditions have been met, otherwise default

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if two cell values overlap in the same row (i.e. any of B-POS, I-POS, U-POS, L-POS - only the POS is required) - set the cell value to match one of the columns (a preferred column) - however that overlap must also have two other row values in 2 other columns with have exactly matching labels.

I have this simplified (non-working) version:

```
import pandas as pd    
my_dict = {'a':['O', 'B-POS', 'I-POS', 'O', 'O'], 'b':['O','O','B-POS','I-POS','I-POS']
               , 'c':['O','O','OPN','O',''], 'd':['O','O','OPN','O','O']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
list_to_make = []

if df['a'].isin(['B-POS', 'I-POS']).any() & df['b'].isin(['B-POS', 'I-POS']).any():
    if df['c']==df['d']:
        list_to_make.extend(df['a'])
    else:
        list_to_make.extend(['O']*len(df['a']))

df['e']=list_to_make
```

I intend to groupby sentence number and then perform this iteratively over each sentence in the dataframe, but it's clearly inefficient and doesn't actually work since the df['c']==df['d'] throws an error.

Is there a better way to compare two columns and if there is a particular value in both columns, to set a new columns values to equal that of the preferred column on the condition that any overlap has a common value in 2 other columns?

I guess in pseudo code-ese:

if

there is a particular value anywhere in a column

and

this value coincides with a (similar) value in another column,

and

at that point (row index) in two other columns there are exact matching values

then

set a new column to match one of the first two columns (a preferred column).

Edit:
forgot to mention: the desired output should match df['a'] since all conditions are fulfilled on 'row[2]' and df['a']'s annotations are preferred.

Comment: You codes do not cover the case where the first `if` is `False` (no `else` for it).  What values for this case ?   Blank or also 'O' ?

Comment: also 'O'. I tried starting with df['e']='O' and then modifying but the 'O's turn back to nans - it seems to update the entire column, rather than just where the preferred column is not 'O'. I suppose I could just fillna('O'), but that code also ran into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

- This code uses `difflib` module to find the similarity metric between strings in column `a` and `b` of the same row
- checks if the similarity is equal or above 80% and assigns appropriate value to column `e`

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib

my_dict = {'a':['O', 'B-POS', 'I-POS', 'O', 'L-POS'], 'b':['O','I-POS','B-POS','I-POS','I-POS']
               , 'c':['O','O','OPN','O',''], 'd':['O','O','OPN','O','O']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
print(df)
df['e'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'] if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x['a'], x['b']).ratio()>=.8
                                       and x['a'] != 'O'
                                       and x['c']==x['d']  else 'O', axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Input**

```
       a      b    c    d
0      O      O    O    O
1  B-POS  I-POS    O    O
2  I-POS  B-POS  OPN  OPN
3      O  I-POS    O    O
4  L-POS  I-POS         O
```

**Output**

```
       a      b    c    d      e
0      O      O    O    O      O
1  B-POS  I-POS    O    O  B-POS
2  I-POS  B-POS  OPN  OPN  I-POS
3      O  I-POS    O    O      O
4  L-POS  I-POS         O      O
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.